# ReactJS - how change html markup dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*I need a reusable component with any markup type decided inside at the coding time, so hardcoding different component would be a very complicating solution, so handling the markup using a function's style would be just awesome.*

Here my sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-clarke-gvrzv?fontsize=14

I would modify my html markup dynamically depending on a javascript variable, as following:

```
let markup= "li"
function App() {
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <[markup]>Hello World</[markup]> 
    </div>
 );
}
```

the console returns me:

```
Unexpected token
```

How handle this problem?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You can use react without jsx syntax. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
const Markup = "li";

return (
  <div className="app">
    <Markup>Hello World</Markup>
  </div>
)
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but you might also consider conditionally rendering a different component:

```
const temperature = -20;

return (
  temperature < 30 ? <Cold /> : <Warm />
);
```

or conditionally swapping the markup inline:

```
const isCold = temp => temp < 30;

const temperature = -12;

return (
  isCold(temperature) ? <div>Brrr!</div> : <span>Sunshine!</span>
);
```

And finally, if you have many possible variants, you can establish a `getComponent` function to figure out what to render:

```
const SeasonalComponents = [
  {
    handles: temp => temp < 0,
    component: () => <div>Brrr!</div>
  },
  {
    handles: temp => temp < 30,
    component: () => <div>Get your coat!</div>
  },
  {
    handles: temp => temp < 50,
    component: () => <div>Just a jacket</div>
  },
  {
    handles: temp => temp < 100,
    component: () => <ImportedSummerComponent />
  }
];

function getComponent (temperature) {
  const seasonal = SeasonalComponents.find(x => x.handles(temperature);
  return seasonal ? seasonal.component : <span>Unseasonable weather!</span>;
}
```

which allows your render method to do a lookup:

```
const Component = getComponent(this.props.temp);

return (
  <Component />
);
```

Comment: awesome, works fine, I need a reusable component with any markup type decided inside at the coding time, so hardcoding different component would be a very complicating solution :/, that said, the cap's Markup works just fine :)!

Comment: just remember to use uppercased the first char of variable name

Comment: I added an example of a component lookup pattern for cases where there are many possibilities.